# Universal maps and moduli spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, moduli-space

I am now reading [this](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/%7Eybilu/algant/documents/theses/Djounvouna.pdf) wonderful thesis on moduli spaces by
Djounvona.

On Proposition 2.5.3 the author says that if you have a moduli functor $\mathcal{M}$ that is represented by an object $M$ in a small category $\mathcal{C}$, then for each family $X/B$ of objects of $\mathcal{M}$ parametrized by each $B$ in $\mathcal{C}$ then there exists a morphism $\varphi : B \to M$.

I can understand how one can set-theoretically define this map, but in any way can see why this have the structure of a morphim of the category $\mathcal{C}$.

Any kind of help will be useful.

Comment: What would it mean to define this map set theoretically? $M$ and $B$ are not sets! This is just the definition of what it means for $\mathcal M$ to be represented by $M$.

Comment: I assumed that the objects of my small category are sets endowed with an extra structure of my category (like schemes). So define this map set-theoretically means that it is possible to relate each point in $B$ with a point in $M$, and this defines a function, but not a morphism.

Comment: Right, you didn't provide nearly all the context. It should be just as I said, but I see the thesis has a whole lot of background details in the setup; if you want to be sure you understand exactly this context you'll need to add all the assumptions to your setup. Note that 2.5.3 doesn't even conclude in a morphism $B\to M$ but $|B|\to M$.

Comment: As I already said in a way I'm sure you're capable of understanding, it is impossible to answer your question when you fail to list all the assumptions on the variables that appear in your problem statement. As you can see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moduli_space#Fine_moduli_spaces, the usual notion of fine moduli space makes this statement tautological, so that your question is entirely dependent on the details of your author's setting. Anyhow, that's certainly more than enough engagement with this for me.